# Network Admin URL is shown to anyone before accessing a blog

Tags: multisite, redirect, security, ssl

I have a multisite setup and I noticed today that my security was not working properly.

Each of my blogs has its own url :

- `http://www.example1.com`
- `http://www.example2.com`
- …

My "main blog" is not in use, its URL exists in order to access the Network admin

- `https://wordpress.example.com`
- `https://wordpress.example.com/wp-admin/network/`

Each time someone visits one of my websites (www1, www2 …) there is an access to

`https://wordpress.example.com/?dm=dcf8262sdfsdff0d8ebcc8608e55e9bf9a&amp;action=load&amp;blogid=9&amp;siteid=1&amp;t=239523830&amp;back=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example2.com%2F`

Now, since my SSL certificate is self-signed and mostly because `https://wordpress.example.com/` is limited to my IP addresses I'm facing an embarrassing issue.

Would anyone know what is happening with this redirection? Is it really necessary?